# Python - Sanitize keys in Sentry logging handler (django)

Tags: python, django, logging, sentry, raven

I'm adding a Sentry logging handler to my Django project. 
I want to customise the sentry handler by adding sanitize keys, and two processors: `raven.processors.SanitizePasswordsProcessor`, `raven.processors.SanitizeKeysProcessor`.

Is there a way to do it in the logging configuration without writing a new handler class, wrapping the `raven.contrib.django.raven_compat.handlers.SentryHandler` class with the parameters I want?

This is my logging config:

```
LOGGING = {
'version': 1,
'disable_existing_loggers': False,
'formatters': {
    'x': {
        #'format': '[%(asctime)s #%(process)d] %(levelname)s: %(message)s'
        'format': '%(asctime)s - %(name)s  - %(levelname)s - %(message)s - {%(pathname)s:%(lineno)d}'
    }
},
'handlers': {
    'console': {
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        'formatter': 'x'
    },
    'sentry': {
        'level': 'ERROR',
        'class': 'raven.contrib.django.raven_compat.handlers.SentryHandler'
    }
},
'loggers': {
    'django': {
        'level': 'INFO',
        'handlers': ['console', 'sentry'],
        'propagate': True
    },
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The `LOGGING` configuration is the wrong place to add these filters, and will not sanitize Sentry events.

As mentioned in the [Client Arguments doc](https://docs.sentry.io/clients/python/advanced/#client-arguments), the correct place is `RAVEN_CONFIG`, also in the Django settings file:

```
RAVEN_CONFIG = {
  'dsn': 'https://<key>:<secret>@sentry.io/<project>',
  'sanitize_keys': [
    'keyname1',
    'keyname2',
  ],
  'processors': (
    'raven.processors.SanitizeKeysProcessor',
    'raven.processors.SanitizePasswordsProcessor',
  )
}
```

Raven is supported for Django 1.4 to 2.0 (see [Django docs](https://docs.sentry.io/clients/python/integrations/#django)). Sentry suggests the new [sentry-sdk](https://docs.sentry.io/error-reporting/quickstart/?platform=python) for Django 2.1 and later, and has [Django integration instructions](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/python/django/). In the [Switching to Sentry-Python post](https://forum.sentry.io/t/switching-to-sentry-python/4733), a comment mentions that [Sentry SDK no longer provides these filters](https://forum.sentry.io/t/switching-to-sentry-python/4733/3), and recommends writing a [custom filter](https://docs.sentry.io/error-reporting/configuration/filtering/?platform=python) if needed. The [send_default_pii parameter](https://docs.sentry.io/error-reporting/configuration/?platform=python#send-default-pii), `False` by default, controls recording and sending a lot of sensitive data, such as IP addresses, user details, and cookies, that were controlled by these filters in the past.